# docker-machine aws driver: how to configure "unlimited vCPU" on t2/t3

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-machine

Want to create a server with `docker-machine` on aws with [this official AWS driver](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/aws/) with a t3 instance with "unlimited vCPU" disabled. Can't find any parameter to do so. Is it just me or is this not possible? Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: Are you wanting to limit the amount of CPU a container can use at one time? Try this out: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/ My assumption is the amount of CPU allowed it X of the total amount available at startup of the container. Let me know how it works out.

Comment: ...would be a workaround indeed. but I have multiple containers running.

Comment: Set the CPU flag for each container, I do that locally to prevent the containers from eating up all my CPU cycles when developing.

Comment: To disable 'unlimited vCPU' I believe you have to un-check the option when creating the EC2 instance. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances-unlimited-mode.html Use in conjunction with the CPU limit per container should get you where you want to be.

Comment: Must work automatic with `docker-machine`. Can't go into console for every machine I create...

Comment: The process to setup an instance w/ docker-machine without the web console is straight forward affair. Setup CLI API, startup a machine, ssh in, install docker machine, exit. Another option is to create a 'golden image' that you gave created that all the EC2 instances will be based from.

Comment: @DavidJEddy There is a much more simple way: use the tool `docker-machine` instead of `docker`from that very server. Check here: https://docs.docker.com/machine/ - we just have the issue with the default settings for t3 to "unlimited vCPUCredits". Seems there is no workaround.

Comment: Very reasonable solution. To disable 'unlimited vCPU' option for the instance I believe that is still an issue of disabling that setting during EC2 instance configuration.